# Unable to create local spark session during scala test. log4j:ERROR Could not create an Appender

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, log4j, azure-application-insights

While trying to create a local spark session in scala test using funsuite I am getting the following error

> log4j:ERROR Could not create an Appender. Reported error follows.
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.microsoft.applicationinsights.log4j.v1_2.ApplicationInsightsAppender
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)   at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)     at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)     at
> java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
> java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
> org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)    at
> org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:247)
> at
> org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:176)
> at
> org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:191)
> at
> org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:523)
> at
> org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseRoot(DOMConfigurator.java:492)
> at
> org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:1006)
> at
> org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:872)
> at
> org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:778)
> at
> org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
> at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.(LogManager.java:127)    at
> org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
> at
> org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.(StaticLoggerBinder.java:72)
> at
> org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.(StaticLoggerBinder.java:45)
> at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)     at
> org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
> at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:417)
> at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:362)    at
> org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:388)     at
> org.apache.spark.network.util.JavaUtils.(JavaUtils.java:41)
> at
> org.apache.spark.internal.config.ConfigHelpers$.byteFromString(ConfigBuilder.scala:67)
> at
> org.apache.spark.internal.config.ConfigBuilder.$anonfun$bytesConf$1(ConfigBuilder.scala:259)
> at
> org.apache.spark.internal.config.ConfigBuilder.$anonfun$bytesConf$1$adapted(ConfigBuilder.scala:259)
> at
> org.apache.spark.internal.config.TypedConfigBuilder.$anonfun$transform$1(ConfigBuilder.scala:101)
> at
> org.apache.spark.internal.config.TypedConfigBuilder.createWithDefault(ConfigBuilder.scala:144)
> at
> org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.(package.scala:345)
> at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.(package.scala)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.(SparkConf.scala:654)  at
> org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.(SparkConf.scala)     at
> org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:94)    at
> org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:83)    at
> org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$1(SparkSession.scala:916)
> at
> scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.$anonfun$foreach$1(HashMap.scala:149)
> at
> scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:237)
> at
> scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.foreachEntry$(HashTable.scala:230)
> at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:44)
> at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:149)  at
> org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:916)
> at
> **com.random.SampleSpec.(SampleSpec.scala:9)**
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)  at
> org.scalatest.tools.DiscoverySuite$.getSuiteInstance(DiscoverySuite.scala:66)
> at
> org.scalatest.tools.DiscoverySuite.$anonfun$nestedSuites$1(DiscoverySuite.scala:38)
> at
> scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
> at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)    at
> scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)    at
> scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)    at
> scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)  at
> scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)     at
> scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)  at
> scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)   at
> scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)  at
> scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)   at
> org.scalatest.tools.DiscoverySuite.(DiscoverySuite.scala:37)    at
> org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.genDiscoSuites$1(Runner.scala:1128)   at
> org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1224)
> at
> org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24(Runner.scala:993)
> at
> org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24$adapted(Runner.scala:971)
> at
> org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1480)
> at
> org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:971)
> at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.main(Runner.scala:775)   at
> org.scalatest.tools.Runner.main(Runner.scala)

Following is the code snippet and test configurations used in pom

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
    import org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfter
    import org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite
    
    class SampleSpec extends AnyFunSuite with BeforeAndAfter {
      val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("SampleTest").getOrCreate()
      spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true")
      spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")
    before {
        spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    
        logger.info("Before")
    
      }
    }
```

```
 <!-- Test -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.version.major}</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0-SNAP3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalacheck/scalacheck -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalacheck</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalacheck_${scala.version.major}</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                    <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                    <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Running this on intelliJ 2021.2.3 version

The same code works in another old module. I tried to replicate almost everything from the old code, but the issue still exists
Tried to invalidate and restart, build and rebuild the module, add framework to support scala but nothing seems to be working

Local spark installation and pom spark version matches i.e., 3.1.3 and scala version is 2.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously your Log4J configuration file (log4j.xml) refers com.microsoft.applicationinsights.log4j.v1_2.ApplicationInsightsAppender as an appender and you do not have as dependency this:

Artifact: applicationinsights-logging-log4j1_2

Group: com.microsoft.azure

Version: 0.9.0

See: https://jar-download.com/maven-repository-class-search.php?search_box=com.microsoft.applicationinsights.log4j.v1_2.ApplicationInsightsAppender

Comment: Thank you. I totally missed the existing log4j.xml file. Deleted the file and rerun. It worked fine.